# How would you get JOSE working in an Expo app?

Tags: react-native, expo, jose

I wrote a small PoC for JOSE which works on Expo web but fails on iOS because it's looking for `crypto` and it's showing can't find variable: `crypto`

Answer (score 0):

A few other packages need to be installed

```
npx expo install expo-random text-encoding buffer expo-standard-web-crypto
```

Then add file that would initialize the polyfills that are needed.

```
// initializePolyfills.ts
global.Buffer = require("buffer").Buffer;
import { polyfillWebCrypto } from "expo-standard-web-crypto";
polyfillWebCrypto();
const TextEncodingPolyfill = require("text-encoding");

Object.assign(global, {
  TextEncoder: TextEncodingPolyfill.TextEncoder,
  TextDecoder: TextEncodingPolyfill.TextDecoder,
});
```

In *app.tsx*, import the file as the first line

```
import './importPolyfills'
...
```

Comment: well, `expo-standard-web-crypto` only has `crypto.getRandomValues()`, so even if it installed the global correctly it wouldn't be enough to do any JOSE operation.

Comment: your best bet at a working ios webcrypto is to use the webkit's webcrypto through a hidden webview. see [1](https://github.com/webview-crypto/react-native-webview-crypto), [2](https://github.com/webview-crypto/webview-crypto) for the approach. Unfortunately, even with this in place the jose lib will not work for you because it doesn't bring in the CryptoKey global. You can however get inspired by the approach and do both SubtleCrypto and jose from within the webview, that will, in theory, work.

Comment: It seems enough for signature verification.  But may be insufficient to do encryption which I haven't tested yet.